# Minimum lcd brightness on android 4.2.1

Tags: 4.2-jelly-bean, screen, root-access, screen-brightness

I'm looking for a way to reduce the real brightness (the backlight) of my lcd. I'm using android 4.2.1 on a Star b94m/b943.

I search for apps, and i found RootDim, which can decrease the light below the minimum 30/255 (default by android).
I found another great app, Velis Auto Brightness, which allows to control the brightness in function of the light sensor. It can't go below the 30/255.
So i thought if there were a method to reduce the default android brightness i could use Velis Auto Brightness (so auto brightness) AND use lower than 30/255 levels.

I tried this tweak of build.prop

[How can I reduce screen brightness below the minimum without an app?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/44270/how-can-i-reduce-screen-brightness-below-the-minimum-without-an-app)

but it didn't work. Any other ideas?

Thank you!

Comment: If you don't mind installing a custom ROM, CyanogenMod ROMs allow much more control of the Brightness setting...Including going below 30/255.

Comment: [This answer](http://android.stackexchange.com/a/82647/96277) should work. Otherwise, try Gravitybox app which definitely would do the job.